# Supporting Android TV and reusing main activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tv

I have an app that I am wanting to be supported by Android TV (the app currently supports phone and tablet)

The main activity is pretty basic, and whilst it does have two text inputs (for an account login) I'm certain it is usable on Android TV (seems to work on the emulator, yet to test on a real Android TV).

So in this case, in my manifest, should I be setting an intent for both `LAUNCHER` and `LEANBACK_LAUNCHER`?

Or should I just set the intent for `LEANBACK_LAUNCHER`?

Comment: If you want to use a single activity for both form factors, yes you can set both intent filters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify both the categories:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

BTW is not recommended to use the same activity layout:

> If you are modifying an existing app for use on TV, your app should
>   not use the same activity layout for TV that it does for phones and
>   tablets. The user interface of your TV app (or TV portion of your
>   existing app) should provide a simpler interface that can be easily
>   navigated using a remote control from a couch. For guidelines on
>   designing an app for TV, see the [TV Design](http://developer.android.com/design/tv/index.html) guide. For more information
>   on the minimum implementation requirements for interface layouts on
>   TV, see [Building TV Layouts](http://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/layouts.html).
>
> Reference:
>   http://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html#tv-activity

Comment: True, but OP can put TV layouts in the `layout-television` resource folder or use the `UIManager` class to change the way that the activity functions if it is a TV.

Comment: Honestly, the interface for the main activity is very very simple. It is currently a basic login form, but in the near future I am changing it to a "keyless" PIN code log in system, utilising a web app (I already use this method for a webOS app)

Comment: Absolutely, mine was only a reminder of the Android TV guidelines. In your case you can to specify both the categories as stated in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

don't forget "Declare Leanback support"

from developer website " If you are developing an app that runs on mobile (phones, wearables, tablets, etc.) as well as Android TV, set the `required` attribute value to false. If you set the `required` attribute value to true, your app will run only on devices that use the Leanback UI."

```
<manifest>
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="false" />
...
```